# Setting an image to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set a background image to a div, but it's not working quite as hoped.

I have a header, a footer, and a sidebar. The header is 80px tall, the footer is 10px tall, and the sidebar extends 250px from the left side of the screen. I want my content div to be the remaining screen.

I have the following code written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing My HTML and CSS</title>
    <style>

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        body .sidebar {
            display:block;
        }

        body.loaded .sidebar {
            display:none;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: black;
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 2;
            color: white;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            top: 80px;
            bottom: 0;
            padding-top: 10px;

        }

        .sidebar li {
            color: black;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            width: 100%;

        }

        .sidebar li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            background-color: #9da1a4;
            width: 100px; 
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid silver; 
            border-radius: 5px; 

        }

        .content {
            height: 340px;
            width: 523px;
            background-image: url("arbor.jpeg");
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .menu-btn {
            background-image: url("menu.png");
            float: left;
            height: 48px;
            width: 44px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-top: -35px;
        }

        .footer {
            width:100%;
            height:30px;
            position:absolute;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
            <div class="menu-btn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
        });

        $(".menu-btn").on("click", function(){
            $(".sidebar").slideToggle(600);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

which can be seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpkzf7wo/).

My goal is to set the image in the `.content` to the background.

I've tried `background-attachment: fixed;`, `background-size: cover`, etc. and it hasn't suited my needs.

Are there any suggestions at all?

Thanks, 
erip

**EDIT**

jsfiddle is a little misleading, so here's a picture of what's happening

[image: Actual result]
The menu button at the top left drives the dropdown.

**EDIT 2**

[image: Edit 2]

After changing the CSS in `.content` to:

```
    .content {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url("arbor.jpeg");
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

I still have 2 problems:

> 1. I want there to be no image from the far left to 250px from the left (i.e., room for the sidebar)
> 2. The page now scrolls. I want the image to fit on a single screen.

I have tried to remedy the 1st problem by playing with `left: 250px;` and `padding-left: 250px;`, but neither worked.

I hope I've provided enough information.

Comment: It looks like it's working on your fiddle.

Comment: See edit for what's problematic.

Comment: @erip you want the image to occupy the entire screen right below your header and footer

Comment: why don't you just make the width of .content to 100%? here take a look http://jsfiddle.net/kpkzf7wo/1/

Comment: you can use this jquery plugin if you need the similar functionality on several images as well - http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kpkzf7wo/3/

Comment: do you mean you want your footer fixed to the bottom?

Comment: I can fix the footer with `absolute`, and I want my background image to be above that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size:cover` actually does serve the purpose that you want, however, if you were to inspect the size-ratio of your HTML elements, you'll find that it's a mess and hence the result is not what you expect.

I've included the solution below, which is almost a complete rework. See whether the result is what you expect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        html,body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        html, body, #home{
            width, height:100%;
        }

        #home{
            min-height:100%;
            position:relative;
        }

        body .sidebar {
            display:block;
        }

        body.loaded .sidebar {
            display:none;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: black;
            height: 80px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 2;
            color: white;
            display:flex; align-items: center; 
            z-index: 1;
            position:relative;
        }

        .menu-btn {
            background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/cT9D02u.png?1);
            height: 48px;
            width: 44px;
            margin-left:50px;
        }

        .header h1{
            width:100%;
            margin:0;padding:0;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            top: 80px;
            bottom: 0;
            padding-top: 10px;

        }

        .sidebar li {
            color: black;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            width: 100%;

        }

        .sidebar li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            background-color: #9da1a4;
            width: 100px; 
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid silver; 
            border-radius: 5px; 

        }

        .content{
            margin-top: -80px; /* Header height */
            height:100%;
            margin-left: 250px;
            background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/3WWnZZj.jpg?1);
            background-size:cover;
        }

        .footer {
            width:100%;
            height:30px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            position:absolute;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('body').addClass('loaded');
            });

            $(".menu-btn").on("click", function(){
                $(".sidebar").slideToggle(600);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Hello World!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <span>Hello</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the rework. I just started writing HTML and CSS a week ago, so I know I'm not very good at it. This works well. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just a quick question -- I added `<!DOCTYPE html>`, as required by HTML5, and this solution didn't work. It's fine how it is, but which part of your fix isn't HTML5 compliant?

Comment: the `width, height:100%` part. just make that into 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

the height and width of `.content` is an issue. Try the following edits, along with removing the height from `.content`:

```
body, html, #home, .content {
  height:100%;
}
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/kpkzf7wo/5/)

Comment: The problem with this is that you can scroll and the footer is no longer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: you have your footer positioned `absolute`, remove that.

Comment: I want `absolute`. I want my image to fill the rest of the screen, not define the size of the screen.

Comment: a background image will never define height, which is the reason for the CSS above.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .content {
                height:100vh;   
                width:100%;     
                background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/3WWnZZj.jpg?1);
                background-size: cover;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've given `.content` fixed dimensions of `height: 340px;` and `width:523px`. `background-size:cover;` is working. The problem is that your div will only ever be 523px x 340px rather than filling the space left by the header and footer, as you intend.

```
.content {
    height: 340px;
    width: 523px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/3WWnZZj.jpg?1);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Admittedly I forgot to change the last-minute changes I had made (i.e., fixing the size of the image). I was getting a closer result by using `background-size: cover;` and `background-attachment: fixed;`, but it would only show the clouds in the image.